# Filling Dynamic ListView with a CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to populate a Dynamic ListView with a CursorAdapter. It's adding new items to the list, but they're all empty. I have NO idea what it is that I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to correct it. Here is my code if you need it.

```
Cursor c = dbHelper.getAllComputers();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        CursorAdapter ca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item, c, new String [] {WOLDbHelper.colName}, new int []{});
        lv.setAdapter(ca);
```

The 'android.R.layout.activity_list_item' is being used sumply because I needed to add a variable.

I setAdapter for the ListView Originally with a static Array and it worked so I know its there, its just not populating correctly? Either that or the SQLite database doesn't have data in the table. And if that's the case, I'm even more lost then I am now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put something in your int[].

Take a look at the actual documentation for a SimpleCursorAdapter. It needs to map, for an item layout, a colum to a view (found by id)

Comment: Got it! Yea, the dynamic bit keeps throwing me off but adding a "android.R.id.text1" into that int [] did the trick. THANKS!